# Reading multiple files in flask submitted through a single button from multiple forms

Tags: html, jquery, forms, flask

I have created a page which has multiple forms and one submit button and the code I have used to submit all the files is:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" id="form1"/>

  <form action="" method="POST" id="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" id="form2"/>

  <form action="" method="POST" id="form3" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" id="form3"/>

 <input type="button" value='Generate Report' onclick="submitForms()"/>
```

And for submitting the button:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function submitForms() {

$("#form1").submit();
$("#form2").submit();
$("#form3").submit();
 }
```

But when I'm trying to read the files through flask, I'm getting this error:

> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser
>   (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

My flask code:

```
@app.route("/upload/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
if request.method=='POST':
    f=request.files['form1']
    p=read.excel(f)
    return str(p.shape)
return render_template('upload.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `action=""` attribute on your forms tells the forms where to submit to.

This should be pointing at your route. `action="/upload"`

Comment: f=request.files['form1']   - i'm getting key error 'form1', how do i read those files.